# Any quick solution to make a view appear behind the status bar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios

I'm porting my app from iOS 6 to IOS 7 (there will eventually be a complete GUI redesign for iOS 7 but in the meanwhile just getting the existing GUI to display properly on iOS 7 is the goal.

I had the issue where the status bar was overlapping my GUI and so have shifted the Y origin of the view controller's view down by 20.

However my app contains a pulldown which when retracted is overlapping with the status bar. In the screenshot the  red is a button which is present in the pulldown view. The grey bar is the top of the main view behind which a portion of pulldown is hiding when retracted.
[image]

I implemented the pull down as a fixed size child subview of the main view and when retracted its Y origin is a negative number thus it is effectively still displayed but off the top of the screen. When the user pulls it down I just animate the increase in the Y origin until eventually the origin is 0.

Is there some way I can make the pull down view appear beneath the status bar or some other quick solution?
Note of course I can't simply toggle the pulldown's alpha to display/hide it as it pullsdown obviously thus its appearance/disappearance is not a discreen action.  I could maybe attempt to make the portion of it that is on top of the status bar invisible but as its something that is moving that seems like its going to be complicated. Is there any simple solution?

Thanks

Comment: You say that you are using a negative Y origin for the retracted view.  Can't you simply increase this negative origin to have the whole view outside the screen?

Comment: No because the very bottom part of the pulldown is visible - it has a pulldown tab image on it so users can see it as a visual clue and tap and drag it down.

Comment: Add another view, with a fixed position, under the status bar (with the same color of your grey bar), 20px tall, but with a z-index higher than the retracting view. This view will cover the retracting view (but not the status bar) acting as a "background" for the status bar itself. Obviously you have to adjust the Y position of the retracting view to make it tappable by the user (but under the status bar).

Comment: Using your idea I increased the width of the status bar view and set its origin to -20 and it looks ok. I'll see if the Product Management dept are happy with the look. Thanks.

Comment: Good, i didn't talk about the width because it was implicit that it was needed to be as large as the screen :-) if you are ok when I come back to the PC I'll write an answer so you can mark it as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another view, with a fixed position, under the status bar (with the same color of your grey bar), 20px tall and same width of the status bar, but with a z-index higher than the retracting view. This view will cover the retracting view (but not the status bar) acting as a "background" for the status bar itself. Obviously you have to adjust the Y position of the retracting view to make it tappable by the user (but under the status bar)

Answer (score -1):

iOS 7 by default lets views take up the fullscreen, including the status bar. This is controlled using the UIRectEdgeAll property.

If you want the old style view, set UIRectEdgeNone for self.edgesForExtendedLayout

in viewDidLoad:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: Because this property works only for extending the view under navigation bars and toolbars, not the status bar

Comment: hmm... ok. I haven't worked on this but only heard it from the iOS 7 Tech Talks.

Would the main problem here be the scrollView?  automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/ios7-weve-got-a-problem/